# Convert int to char of int value

Tags: c++, char, int

I'm trying to find a way to convert an `int` to `char` of the corresponding value of the `int` (assuming int is one digit). (example 1='1' 5='5' 9='9') I've tried

```
int a=5;
char b=char(a+48);
```

whenever I try to run this the program crashes. How can I set up a system that works correctly?

Comment: The program crashes for some completely unrelated reason that you haven't told us anything about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using the following code:

```
char c = (char)(48 + a);
```

You can also use the `'0'` char value, instead of 48. It will improve code readability and let you not remember the value 48:

```
int a = 5;
char c = (char)((int)'0' + a);
```

As mentioned in comments, you can do this without explicit casts:

```
char c = '0' + a;
```

Comment: Where exactly did you spot the incorrect syntax? Clearly the OP is asking, why the program is crashing. A prerequisite to crashing is compiling.

Comment: That is a perfectly valid C++ function-style cast. It is not invalid syntax.

Comment: @immibis Thank you for clarification. I have removed the confusing part.

Comment: You can simply use `char c = '0' + a;`, there is no need for explicit casts.

Comment: At least eliminate the cast `(int)'0'`.